# IBM DB2 JDBC connection to cataloged database via SSL

Tags: ssl, jdbc, db2

1) I cataloged a remote database DBSAMPLE(remote port 52000) with SSL locally.    And I can connect to it via db2 command line (local name alias SAMPLOC). Local db2 port 50000.

2) I can connect to the remote DB via JDBC:

```
        jdbc:db2://serv.com:52000/DBSAMPLE:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=truststore.jks;sslTrustStorePassword=xxxx;
```

3) How can I connect to the cataloged SAMPLOC(aka DBSAMPLE) via JDBC? What URL should I use?

```
        jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLOC:sslConnection=true;
```

Does not work:

```
        com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException   Error Code: -4499   SQL State: 08001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Db2) [JDBC has type 4 and type 2 drivers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjdcon.html) with different properties. With a type 4 driver you would directly connect to the remote Db2 database. The [type 2 driver](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052341.html) allows connecting through the local Db2 instance using the information that is cataloged about the remote database. The [connection format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052341.html) is special:

```
jdbc:db2:SAMPLOC
```

SAMPLOC is the name of the local database alias. Depending on security, would need to provide the username and password as parameters. See the link for details.

Comment: In addition, you can connect *locally* via SSL with the type-4 driver and the same URL format as remote-connections, if and only if you configure correctly and require local connections to be encrypted.

Comment: Using the Type 2 driver syntax will only provide an encrypted connection if SAMPLOC has been cataloged at the DB2 client level to use SSL.